# VS .Net References with yellow triangle

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I work on a project with one more developer and we share our code via Git, everything works great until yesterday, after I pulled the last commit, All my references got Yellow triangle with the following Warning:

```
The referenced component '------' could not be found.
```

also you can see it in the screenshot bellow:
[image]

I want to fix it, i didn't find solutions for this problem. I'll be happy to get your help! Thanks.

Comment: Did you try and "build" the solution? Is your solution set up to get the missing packages from nuget on build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good way to solve this is to delete the reference and Install it from nuget again. Or pull the DLL from Git individually and then add them to the project.

Comment: But is that a good long term solution? Would be curious about root cause if happens again.  Also is this with .NET Core or Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking that App.config & web.config aren't damaged and that Nuget packages are restored/installed in an existing directory?

Comment: I also have the following error:
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is...

Comment: Open NuGet Manager and it should ask you at the top if you want to restore. Otherwise, here is some more info on restoring [NuGet Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore)